# DB Sync Media Files extension

Tags: plugins, sync

I've installed [WP DB Sync](https://github.com/wp-sync-db) (master branch) in three different WP instances. I've also installed the [WP DB Sync Media Files extension](https://github.com/wp-sync-db/wp-sync-db-media-files) (master branch), however the "Media Files" checkbox is not showing up in the backend. I've also opened a [issue](https://github.com/wp-sync-db/wp-sync-db-media-files/issues/31) at github, but no reply so far.

Is there anything special I should do to make the WP DB Sync Media Files extension work, beyond unzipping it in the plugins folder and activating it?

Comment: plugin specific questions are off-topic

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that because this is a github hosted plugin, so it's totally community developed. Considering my answer below spots the problem in the plugin code, maybe we can deduce this question should be moved to stackoverflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there's another required step: I must enter the correct connection informations before the checkbox shows up.

The JS code checks for the connection, talks to the remote plugin and if it finds it's all ok, lets the checkbox display itself. In other cases [it hides the checkbox](https://github.com/wp-sync-db/wp-sync-db-media-files/blob/c14b6128e506006a8502684c66690f2e2129483a/asset/js/script.js#L52).

Now I believe this plugin has a weird design, because implementing in JS (client side) a server-to-server migration is at least a strange choice, but that's another pair of shoes.